# How android apps can communicate with each other?

Tags: android

I need a way to communicate and control from my app, every other app in a mobile android device.

Is there any communication protocol like SOAP (Web Services) for installed android apps?

I have found a way to open from my app, other apps but I can not control them to send and receive data.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Comment: That is not answers my question.

Comment: It does. It explains:
1. Starting another application
2. Sending data as part of that Intent
3. Receiveing data from that application as a result

Comment: What do you mean by control? As Tristan mentioned above you can use intents to send and receive data from one app to another if proper intent filters are declared on both sides. Alternatively, you might look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: The ONLY way to "control" another app is with an `Intent`.  Basic security design of Android.

Answer (score 3):

> I need a way to communicate and control from my app, every other app in a mobile android device.

That is not generally possible. Few apps expose any sort of API that third-party apps can use to "communicate and control", outside of making a launcher activity available.

> Is there any communication protocol like SOAP (Web Services) for installed android apps?

An app can choose to allow third-party apps:

- start one of the app's activities, or
- start or bind to one of the app's services, or
- work with one of the app's `ContentProviders`, or
- send broadcasts to the app

All of these (activities, services, providers, receivers) represent Android components. Those components that are exported can be invoked by third-party apps, through IPC, subject to any security conditions the app may put in place (e.g., third-party app must hold a certain permission).

Whether an app does any of this, and to what extent that it does, is up to the author of the app. This is no different than with Web services -- you, the client, cannot force a Web site to magically sprout a SOAP Web service. Similarly, you, the client, cannot force an app to magically sprout one of these IPC mechanisms.